# CS0029 C# 'Cannot implicitly convert type string[] to string'

Tags: c#, .net, taglib

I'm making an application to edit the properties of .mp3 files. I have to say I'm pretty new to programming and stackoverflow, so I might be doing something very obviously wrong. Please forgive me! This is the code I am using:

```
private void btnApply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var file = TagLib.File.Create(filepath);
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtGenre.Text))
    {
        file.Tag.Genres = new string[] {txtGenre.Text};
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtArtist.Text))
    {
        file.Tag.Performers = new string[] {txtArtist.Text};
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtTitle.Text))
    {
        file.Tag.Title = new string[] {txtTitle.Text};
    }
    file.Tag.Performers = new string[] { txtArtist.Text };
    file.Tag.Title = txtTitle.Text;
    file.Save();

    if (!ReadFile())
    {
        Close();
    }
}
```

The odd thing to me is that I only get an error for this part:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtTitle.Text))
{
    file.Tag.Title = new string[] {txtTitle.Text};
}
```

With this being underlined red:

```
new string[] {txtTitle.Text}
```

What am I missing here? I've been looking for a very long time but I just can't seem to find any solutions. Thank you in advance! I am also using TagLib, by the way.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between `string` and `string[]`?

Comment: You are trying to put a `string[]` value into a `string` variable. `file.Tag.Title` is a `string`

Comment: You can try with: `file.Tag.Title = txtTitle.Text;`

Comment: @Luctia Please don't mangle question titles with status information like "SOLVED:". Accepting answers is here for this purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this:

```
file.Tag.Title = new string[] {txtTitle.Text};
```

to:

```
file.Tag.Title = txtTitle.Text;
```

`Title` type is `string`, not array of strings (not `string[]`), but you try to assign array - because of it you get error. Other fields have type `string[]` (array of strings), that's why you get error only with `Title`.

Also, you try to assign value to `Title` 2 times:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtTitle.Text))
{
    file.Tag.Title = new string[] {txtTitle.Text};    // first time
}
file.Tag.Performers = new string[] { txtArtist.Text };
file.Tag.Title = txtTitle.Text;                       //second time
```

You need to assign only one time. Also, when you assign second time you assign it correctly without error.

The same situation with `Performers` - you assign first time inside `if` statement and second time after the last `if`.

Comment: Thanks, this removed the underlining, but it doesn't work as intended. The idea is to not edit anything when the textbox is empty. This works with txt.Genre, but not with title or artist. Going to have to figure that one out myself, I suppose. Thanks nonetheless!

Comment: @Luctia, see edited answer. Delete two lines before `file.Save()`. These lines: `file.Tag.Performers = new string[] { txtArtist.Text };` and `file.Tag.Title = txtTitle.Text;`

Comment: Ah yes, I tried and tested that just now. It works now. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Change the code like this and try

```
file.Tag.Title = txtTitle.Text;
```